# Sorting by Columns in data

Tags: r, sorting

I have the following dataset. I want to sort it by second column.

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
                  ID  LFrom LTo It1 It2 It3 It4
                  ab7    1   2   47  152 259 140
                  ab8   1.1   2.1   88  236 251 145
                  ab21   1.2   2.1  72  263 331 147
                  ab3    1   2   71  207 290 242
                  ab300    1   2   47  152 259 140
                  ab4    1.2   2.1  72  263 331 147
                  ab10    1.1   2   71  207 290 242
                  ab501    1   2   47  152 259 140
                  ")

dat
     ID LFrom LTo It1 It2 It3 It4
1   ab7   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140
2   ab8   1.1 2.1  88 236 251 145
3  ab21   1.2 2.1  72 263 331 147
4   ab3   1.0 2.0  71 207 290 242
5 ab300   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140
6   ab4   1.2 2.1  72 263 331 147
7  ab10   1.1 2.0  71 207 290 242
8 ab501   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140
```

By using the following code, I find:

```
dat[with(dat, order(LFrom, ID)),]
     ID LFrom LTo It1 It2 It3 It4
4   ab3   1.0 2.0  71 207 290 242
5 ab300   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140
8 ab501   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140
1   ab7   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140
7  ab10   1.1 2.0  71 207 290 242
2   ab8   1.1 2.1  88 236 251 145
3  ab21   1.2 2.1  72 263 331 147
6   ab4   1.2 2.1  72 263 331 147
```

The sorting in `ID` is not really sorted according to the number value. I rewrite the data by putting extra `00` and `0` (manually) like the following:

```
dat1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
                  ID  LFrom LTo It1 It2 It3 It4
                  ab007    1   2   47  152 259 140
                  ab008   1.1   2.1   88  236 251 145
                  ab021   1.2   2.1  72  263 331 147
                  ab003    1   2   71  207 290 242
                  ab300    1   2   47  152 259 140
                  ab004    1.2   2.1  72  263 331 147
                  ab010    1.1   2   71  207 290 242
                  ab501    1   2   47  152 259 140
                  ")
dat1
     ID LFrom LTo It1 It2 It3 It4
1 ab007   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140
2 ab008   1.1 2.1  88 236 251 145
3 ab021   1.2 2.1  72 263 331 147
4 ab003   1.0 2.0  71 207 290 242
5 ab300   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140
6 ab004   1.2 2.1  72 263 331 147
7 ab010   1.1 2.0  71 207 290 242
8 ab501   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140
```

Now the following code works fine:

```
dat1[with(dat1, order(LFrom, ID)), ]
     ID LFrom LTo It1 It2 It3 It4
4 ab003   1.0 2.0  71 207 290 242
1 ab007   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140
5 ab300   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140
8 ab501   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140
2 ab008   1.1 2.1  88 236 251 145
7 ab010   1.1 2.0  71 207 290 242
6 ab004   1.2 2.1  72 263 331 147
3 ab021   1.2 2.1  72 263 331 147
```

I have a large list of dataset. Manually changing the `ID` is tough. All I need to get the `ID` sorted (with including `00` and `0`).

Comment: It orders the columns by the order of the arguments, `LFrom` first, then `ID`.  It looks like it's working fine.  Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Does ID follow a consistent format that you know in advance? i.e., set of characters values by a set of numeric values.

Comment: @mispelled, The numeric value of ID is 3 digit (max) and it has a consistent form in the beginning as "ab".

Comment: @RichardScriven, I think he is asking a way to programmatically pad the string such that he will get consistent sorting behavior. He mentioned manually changing the ID is tough with a large list of datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the with a combination of `substr` and `sprintf` as follows:

```
dat$ID <- paste0(substr(dat$ID,1,2),sprintf("%03d",as.numeric(substr(dat$ID,3,5))))
```

this gives:

```
> dat[with(dat, order(LFrom, ID)), ]
     ID LFrom LTo It1 It2 It3 It4
4 ab003   1.0 2.0  71 207 290 242
1 ab007   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140
5 ab300   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140
8 ab501   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140
2 ab008   1.1 2.1  88 236 251 145
7 ab010   1.1 2.0  71 207 290 242
6 ab004   1.2 2.1  72 263 331 147
3 ab021   1.2 2.1  72 263 331 147
```

Answer (score 1):

use data.table:

```
library(data.table)

dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
                 ID  LFrom LTo It1 It2 It3 It4
                  ab7    1   2   47  152 259 140
                  ab8   1.1   2.1   88  236 251 145
                  ab21   1.2   2.1  72  263 331 147
                  ab3    1   2   71  207 290 242
                  ab300    1   2   47  152 259 140
                  ab4    1.2   2.1  72  263 331 147
                  ab10    1.1   2   71  207 290 242
                  ab501    1   2   47  152 259 140
                  ")
DT = as.data.table(dat1)

 DT[, newID:=gsub("ab", "", ID)]
   DT[order(LFrom, newID),]
      ID LFrom LTo It1 It2 It3 It4 newID
1: ab003   1.0 2.0  71 207 290 242   003
2: ab007   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140   007
3: ab300   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140   300
4: ab501   1.0 2.0  47 152 259 140   501
5: ab008   1.1 2.1  88 236 251 145   008
6: ab010   1.1 2.0  71 207 290 242   010
7: ab004   1.2 2.1  72 263 331 147   004
8: ab021   1.2 2.1  72 263 331 147   021
```

Or just

```
library(data.table)
DT = as.data.table(dat1)
DT[order(LFrom, gsub("ab", "", ID)),]
```

Without data.table it would be:

```
dat1[with(dat1, order(LFrom, gsub("ab", "", ID))), ]
```